# How to get the image path from webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have something like this in my webpack.config.js:

```
    {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    }
```

So if I do

```
import 'path/to/image.png';
```

Webpack does find the image and makes sure it can load it.

How do I go if I want to make use of the image in my JavaScript code.

Often APIs require something like this:

```
let options = {
  iconPath: 'path/to',
  iconImg: 'path/to/image.png'
}
```

What do I put instead of the path?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I would also like to get the generated path from an import, inside a JS file but could find anything online except from your Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

import png from 'path/to/image.png';

You can use png in your img src

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it , you have already provided the path as 'path/to/image.png' This is the location from where webpack has bundled it

Comment: Yes, but at rutime the path is different. It would be something like `build/1092712410923f84.png`. So if an API requires just the path and not a single image. How can I go about that?